# Using str.decode with errors='replace' still gives errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace some text ('id' -> 'doc_id') in hundreds of JSON files. The files include text scraped from the internet, text encoding should be utf-8 but maybe not all the time. I tried to read the files in binary, then decode into utf-8, then replace the text and then write to file. The encoding part has errors='replace' but I still get errors! And the funny part is that if I run the program multiple times, it gets stuck on different files.

Why am I getting errors even with 'replace'?

Here is the code:

```
import os

folder = 'C:\\some\\path'

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.json'):
        print('Processing: ', file)
        f = open(file, 'rb')
        binary_text = f.read()
        f.close()
        decoded_text = binary_text.decode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace')
        replaced_text = decoded_text.replace('"id":', '"doc_id":')
        f = open(file, 'w')
        f.write(replaced_text)
        f.close()

print('Done!')
```

This is one of the example errors I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\some\path\id_to_docid.py", line 13, in <module>
    binary_text = f.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7423: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You are not getting an error with the `decode()` method but before, at the line `binary_text = f.read()`.

Comment: Hmm the code looks correct to me.
Are you 100% sure, that the error message corresponds exactly to the python code in the question above?

It looks as if you had written:
`f = open(file, 'r')` and then `binary_text = f.read()` instead of opening in mode "rb"

If you have any doubt, then copy the code of your question into a python file and call it.

Just to be sure there is not a minor difference.

Comment: You could try adding `errors='ignore'` to your call to `open()` but it is not very recommended:  it may result in data loss when unknown characters are encountered...

Comment: hmm, I may have accidentally copied the wrong traceback... here is the one I got just now when I tried to run the code:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\some\path\id_to_docid.py", line 18, in <module>
    f.write(replaced_text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 4217: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: And I noticed that now every time I run the code it gets one file further than the last time. So it gets through 19 files just fine but then gives the error. And if I run it again, it get through 20 files until error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have found the problem. The latter 
`f = open(file, 'w')`
should also be 
`f = open(file, 'w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace')`
Now everything runs smoothly. A rookie mistake, I guess...